# Sum of binomial coefficients $\sum_{k=n}^{r}\binom{k}{n}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

*Is is possible to find the sum of a binomial coefficient series like*: $\sum_{k=n}^{r}\dbinom{k}{n}$? 
Just a random thought.

Comment: If you have meant $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n r\binom nr$

$$\displaystyle r\binom nr=r\dfrac{n\cdot(n-1)!}{r\cdot(r-1)!\{n-1-(r-1)\}!}=n\binom{n-1}{r-1}$$

Comment: ${k \choose n} = 0$ if $k < n$, $1$ if $k=n$.  Maybe you'd rather do
$$\sum_{k=n}^r {k \choose n}$$

Comment: yeah yeah im so sorry... i didnt notice the flaw in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \sum_{k=n}^r {k \choose n} = \dfrac{r+1-n}{n+1} {r+1 \choose n} $$
Prove by induction on $r$.

EDIT: Actually this can be written as $${r+1 \choose n+1}$$
in which form it has a nice combinatorial interpretation.  Suppose you want to have $r+1$ objects numbered $1$ to $r+1$, and you want to choose $n+1$ of them.  How many ways to do it?  Divide into cases according to the highest-numbered object chosen.  If the highest-numbered object chosen has number $k+1$, the remaining $n$ objects can be chosen from $1,\ldots, k$ in ${k \choose n}$ ways, where of course we need $k \ge n$.  Therefore
$$ {{r+1} \choose {n+1}} = \sum_{k=n}^r {k \choose n}$$

Comment: Please give a proof without induction.Or provide the source of the formula you stated.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = n}^{r}{k \choose n}} & =
\sum_{k = n}^{r}\overbrace{%
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{k} \over z^{n + 1}}\,
{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{{k \choose n}}} =
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{n + 1}}\sum_{k = n}^{r}\,
\pars{1 + z}^{k}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm] & =
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{n + 1}}
\pars{1 + z}^{n}\,{\pars{1 + z}^{r - n + 1} - 1 \over \pars{1 + z} - 1}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm] & =
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{r + 1} \over z^{n + 2}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} -
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n + 2}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} = {r + 1 \choose n + 1}\ -\
\overbrace{{n \choose n + 1}}^{\ds{=\ 0}}
\\[3mm] & = \color{#f00}{{r + 1 \choose n + 1}}
\end{align}